# Plotting Time series with different colors in R

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I want to plot a time series with different colors based on factors.
I tried splitting the time series by factor, then plotting using

```
plot(x1, col= "orange", xlab="Time", font.main=2, cex.main=1.5,
   ylim = c(-8, 10.5), ylab = "Y", main= "X")


lines(x2, col= "red")
  lines(x3, col="yellow")
```

But this is the result:

[image: Plot]

It's almost near to what i need, but of course i want to remove those lines which connect the different parts.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
a <- rnorm(200)
k <- sample(c("red", "green", "blue", "brown"), 200, replace = T)
plot(a, type = "h", col = k)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. I think we are close to the solution, but this is not what I'm looking for. This is what my time series looks like: https://i.imgur.com/ukbm7ZN.png If the value is 3, it must be orange, if 2, red and if 1, yellow. It should be as similar as possible to the img I posted in the thread, but without those "connection lines"

Comment: I tried to work following your advice of using "type = "h" " and it worked, thank you so much!